# Можно ли определять длину QString через sizeof?

Tags: qt, c++

Есть следующий код инверсии:

```
   void Inversion(QString str)
    {
        QString result;
        for(int i = sizeof(str)-1, j = 0; i >=0; --i, ++j)
        {
            result[j] = str[i];
        }
        QMessageBox msg;
        msg.setText(result+"");
        msg.exec();
    }
```

Нашел этот пример в одном уроке по qt, то есть тут определяется размер самого стринга, а не количества символа в нем? Самое смешное, что я вначале даже купился на это, как и автор туториала, потому что он ввел слово из 5 букв, которое как раз сработало совпам с размером стринга), но все, что длиннее 5 символов, будет обрезаться. То есть нужно заменить на `str.length()-1`.

А насколько валиден такой алгоритм при инверсии не только английских, но и русских символов? Он-то работает, но хотелось бы знать, не зря ли я убежал от консоли с досовской кодировкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, этот алгоритм обращения Юникодной строки неверен. Он не учитывает наличие [combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). Пример: строка `оё` *может* быть представлена в Unicode как `"o\u0308е"`, после «наивного» разворота превратится в `"е\u0308о"`, то есть `еö`.

Обязательное чтение по теме от героя параллельного форума Джона Скита: [OMG PONIES!!!](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/) (Перевод не нашёл.) Если вам скучно читать всё (я бы посоветовал, не пожалеете), поищите на странице «However, let’s take the fact».

Comment: [Здесь](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#details) еще одно подтверждение (и добавка -- *surrogate pairs*):

    QString stores a string of 16-bit QChars, where each QChar corresponds one Unicode 4.0 character. (Unicode characters with code values above 65535 are stored using surrogate pairs, i.e., two consecutive QChars.)

Те же грабли в Java, C#, Javascript, Python (частично, зависит от сборки, но от combining characters не спасает) ...  
Интересно, когда же эта проблема будет решена?

Comment: @VladD, получается (в свете combining characters) даже UCS-4 надо последовательно анализировать. Т.е. по сути никакого (почти) алгоритмического выигрыша перед utf-8 (если все делать совсем правильно).

Comment: @avp: Я бы сказал, надо изгнать из стандарта всякую диакритику и композиционные правила. Один символ = один code point, и если это будет означать 8 байт на символ в памяти, то так тому и быть. (Другое дело, что на диске стоит держать в utf-8.)

Comment: @avp: Сейчас можно лишь написать вспомогательный метод, который разбивает строку на подстроки (в основном единичной длины), соответствующие одной букве. Надеюсь, что это возможно :( И надеюсь, что это есть во фреймворках.

Comment: @VladD, мне кажется, что когда мы доживем до 64-bit символов диски станут уже неактуальными  
(см. **мемристор** -- огромная быстрая *энергонезависимая* память).

Наверное это должно привести к существенным изменениям вообще в парадигмах программирования.

Comment: @avp: Было бы замечательно! Программы под смартфоны, например, работают _уже_ по такому принципу. Приложение как бы никогда не закрывается, вы просто переключаетесь между запущенными приложениями.

Для того, чтобы изобразить такое, приложениям приходится при выгрузке их памяти запоминать своё состояние, а при повторном запуске считывать и притворяться, что ничего не случилось. С огромной энергонезависимой памятью это было бы естественным поведением!

Answer (score 2):

Для ответа на вопрос:

```
 насколько валиден такой алгоритм при инверсии не только английских, но и русских символов?
```

достаточно такого самостоятельного эксперимента:

```
  printf("size of letter: %d (%s)\n", 
         (int)sizeof(str[0]), sizeof(str[0]) > 1 ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Заодно узнаете, какой unicode (16 или 32) используется.

**Обновление**

Вот вроде [хорошая статья про юникод](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx) попалась  (с кучей полезных ссылок и не слишком длинная).

---

Ответ на Ваш *конкретный вопрос*:

```
 А насколько валиден такой алгоритм при инверсии не только английских, но и русских символов?
```

Чисто русские (конечно, в смеси с ASCII тоже) тексты Вы можете безбоязненно переворачивать этим алгоритмом, поскольку диакритика и прочие композиции (в т.ч. суррогатные пары) в русском (про другие кириллические не знаю) тексте не используется.

Comment: После ответа @VladD надо отметить, что даже `4` в ответе  не спасает...

Comment: @xinakapu, Обновил ответ

Comment: @avp: Боюсь, проблемы могут встретиться и в кириллице: <http://ideone.com/Nx5Tn2>. Да и на английском попадаются всевозможные _café_ и _naïveté_.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за информацию. 

Никогда раньше даже не слышал о *нормализации* буквы `й` (и видимо `ё`). Хотя, наверное это логично, если обобщать  графические элементы, изображающие буквы любого языка.  
(а вот для программирования -- просто "нож острый")

Comment: @avp: Я вот как раз сейчас читаю [оф. документацию](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) и ужасаюсь. И [вот](http://www.macchiato.com/unicode/globalization-gotchas) ещё.

Comment: @VladD, я тоже. Пока бегло просмотрел.

Впечатление, что мы никогда это правильно не реализуем (да и захотим ли?).

Answer (score 1):

QString хранит данные в юникод-кодировке. QString можно использовать для всех языков, поддерживаемых кодировкой.

Answer (score 0):

имхо, это очевидный изврат. `sizeof()` предназначен для других вещей совсем, и вы правильно считаете, что его нужно заменить на `str.length()`. А алгоритм - да, работает, как и указал AlekseyOk. Я проверил для юникод-строки, переставляет правильно. Очевидно потому, что оператор [] в QString возвращает unicode-16 символ, поэтому и кодировка не бьётся.